# Bootstrap 4 not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">A</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap version is 4 alpha. Those two columns are next to each other and are 50% width on all (320, 480, 720, 1024, 1440 etc.) resolutions. I seem to recall Bootstrap switching to 100% width once you reach the mobile resolutions but it's not doing it anymore.

Did I do something wrong or did Bootstrap stop being responsive?

Comment: you have to use col-xs-12 not col-12

Comment: Maybe you didn't add the boostrap properly. try the cdn from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @Roy Bootstrap4 dropped `col-xs-*` for `col-*`.

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru the bootstrap file loads just fine, I can see the classes being applied in Chrome Devtoops. I've tried with CDN too, doesn't work either.

Comment: Works fine here: https://www.codeply.com/go/eylPCukNEt Can you provide an example of it not working?

Comment: @Vedranhave have you read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700276/not-able-to-make-bootstrap-responsive-design-work-with-dotnetnuke ?

Comment: @Turnip that worked, thanks! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I'd also add that Bootstrap 4 is now beta. I'd advise against using the alpha build, as there were some changes between the two.